# How to design BJT active filters?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, active-filter

In High school and University courses, I have only seen active filters made around op-amps. I'd like to know something about active filters built with BJT amplifiers.

[image: Example of BJT filter compared to op-amp version]
<sup>Example of BJT filter compared to op-amp version</sup>

I can find lots of information in books I have about op-amp filters, but nothing about BJT filters. I searched a lot also on the Internet, but I found very little information.

How to design filters with BJTs, and what are the advantages/disadvantages versus op-amp circuits (costs, performance, noise, etc.)?

Moreover, can you please suggest me a good book or some lectures to better understand these kind of filters?

Comment: Unless you are doing custom RF filters >> 1MHz  why would you want a less accurate filter with low gain and thermal drift? Quad Op Amps are only 0.25$ in single supply with <50mV near Rail2Rail  Low input offset voltage: ±1 mV
• Rail-to-rail output
• Unity-gain bandwidth: 1 MHz
• Low broadband noise: 30 nV/√Hz
• Low input bias current: 10 pA
• Low quiescent current: 70 µA/Ch
• Unity-gain stable
• Internal RFI and EMI filter

Comment: Alessio, the *only* place where I've seen some discussion of using BJTs in place of opamps is in Don Lancaster's "Active Filter Cookbook." It's an old book and some terms used there will need to be "interpreted" into more modern contexts (things have changed over the years.) But it covers these. Opamps today are so much more common, cheap, and don't have some of the liabilities of early opamps. So it's almost always better to use an opamp today. However, a BJT is dirt cheap, has only three pins instead of at least 5, and can be used effectively. Read "old stuff" if you are serious about this.

Comment: Alessio, I should correct myself -- a little. Sallen & Key in their TR-50 paper from 1954 (developed from an MIT contract from the US Air Force) discusses circuits using vacuum tubes. To a lesser degree, so does their 1955 paper published in IRE Transactions -- Circuit Theory. Their use of cathode followers is very close to what you want, as well.

Comment: @jonk I guess Don Lancaster's Active Filter Cookbook is a great start point to active filters (at least for me as a beginner) but I could not find any "recipe" using BJTs. In the first chapter there is a brief example using BJT of an active low pass filter but aside that BJTs are mentioned in between explanations of apamps internal structures. I got the 1975 (1st edition) version of the book.

Answer (score 3):

a bipolar running at 10mA will have Rout (Zout!) of 2.6 ohms; and you can run this circuit on 1v or 1.5 volts, unlike an opamp. Thus the bipolar STOPBAND will be far
superior to the opamp.

Note for each of your schematics, the C2 becomes a shunting path for high frequencies,
and the only filtering remains the C1 (thus one-pole passive becomes the behavior).

The 0.6 volt offset can be reduced, with a NPN/PNP Darlington.

The inherent noise of a bipolar is set by the rbb', which is the non-useful resistance
of the bulk silicon material between base-contact node and base-collector region; you should easily have this less than 1,000 ohms, or 4 nanoVolt/rtHz noise density. In 1MHz bandwidth, you'll have 4 microVolts RMS (scaled up by pi/2 or so, for rolloff) of total integrated random (and white) noise.

Thus with 1 volt PP input, and 4 microVolts RMS noise, you can expect about 100dB SNR.

Do be aware of Finite Power Supply Rejection, likely set by the Early Voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to take filters designed for op-amps configured at unity gain, (as in your second schematic), and apply them directly to BJTs in emitter follower configuration (as in your first schematic).

Comment: ...but you should know that the exactness of the desired filter response will be not as good as the opamp based realization - due to a larger output resistance and a smaller input resistance (if compared with an opamp). Howevr, a simulation program can be used to correct the filter response...

Comment: If the emitter follower is working into a constant current load, the response will be pretty close.

Comment: No - the emitter resistance - even if it is a "constant" current - does NOT determine the output resistance. For each emitter follower the output resistance is determined by the inverse transconductance (several ohms, typically), which is much larger than the output resistance of a unity-gain opamp (milliohms due to feedback).

Comment: no of course not, but it affects the input resistance. And as (for the filters I was designing) the impedances were in the kilohms and higher, several ohms Zout was at most, comparable with the tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, we first have to get an overview of the different principles for realizing active filters:

A) Filter stages

1) with finite and fixed gain

2) with (nearly) infinite amplification

3) with impedance converters (GIC)

B) Active component simulation of passive filter structures (GIC technology, integrator stages).

If one knows the properties of the bipolar transistor (BJT), it becomes immediately clear that actually only the realization A1 is promising:

Sallen-Key structures with a finite and fixed gain value, whereby there are circuits for both positive and negative gain values.

**Remark**: In 1955 R.P.Sallen and E.L.Key published a fundamental paper in IRE-CT2 in which bipolar transistors were used for realizing active filter topologies.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but...

Maybe the answer to some part of this question can be found in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/649685/319794) to [BJT Active low-pass filter frequency calculation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/649678/64015).

At least to design an active filter using BJTs. In my beginner's perspective, I would implement a passive LC or RLC filter and after that try to replace the inductors with transistors.